# Add different value to each column in array

Tags: bash, awk

How can i add a different value to each column in a bash script?

Example: Three function f1(x) f2(x) f3(x) plotted over x

test.dat:

```
# x  f1    f2    f3 
1    0.1  0.01  0.001
2    0.2  0.02  0.002
3    0.3  0.03  0.003
```

Now i want to add to each function a different offset value

```
values = 1 2 3
```

Desired result:

```
# x  f1    f2    f3 
1    1.1  2.01  3.001
2    1.2  2.02  3.002
3    1.3  2.03  3.003
```

So first column should be unaffected, otherwise the value added.

I tried this, but it doesn work

```
declare -a energy_array=( 1 2 3 )

for (( i =0 ; i <  ${#energy_array[@]} ; i ++ ))
do
local energy=${energy_array[${i}]}
cat "test.dat" \
 | awk -v "offset=${energy}" \ 
'{ for(j=2; j<NF;j++) printf "%s",$j+offset OFS; if (NF) printf "%s",$NF; printf ORS} '
done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try the following:

```
declare -a energy_array=( 1 2 3 )
awk -voffset="${energy_array[*]}" \
'BEGIN { n=split(offset,a) } 
 NR> 1{ 
   for(j=2; j<=NF;j++) 
      $j=$j+a[j-1]
   print;next
 }1' test.dat
```

With output:

```
# x  f1    f2    f3 
1 1.1 2.01 3.001
2 1.2 2.02 3.002
3 1.3 2.03 3.003
```